# How to disable garbage collection threads in OpenJDK?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm working on a JVM project where I need to disable garbage collection in JVM and get the out of memory error.

When we call system.gc(), GC gets called after sometime and I also wrote a program which invokes GC without calling system.gc(). And it seems like they both follow the different call stacks while invoking GC.

I need to disable the GC for my research project purpose and how can I do that.

Where do GC threads get scheduled in the OpenJDK code for the program which doesn't call system.gc() explicitly.

I'm using OpenJDK 11.

Comment: “and I wrote a program which invokes GC without calling system.gc()” This doesn’t make any sense. “And it seems like they both follow…” Which “both” are you talking about? You described only one program.

Comment: One program with System.gc() and one without calling system.gc().    I created a lot of objects and freed a few objects randomly and again crrated a few more objects. This program invokes GC without explicitly calling system.gc() is what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to disable garbage collection entirely. **Java 11** comes with an [Epsilon](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318)(no-op garbage collector). In JEP 318:

> Develop a GC that handles memory allocation but does not implement any actual memory reclamation mechanism. Once the available Java heap is exhausted, the JVM will shut down.

So, after a while will see the out of memory error. It can be enabled by the `-XX:+UseEpsilonGC` option at JVM start.